# Using cache task in Azure Devops

Tags: npm, azure-devops, node-modules

I'm using the cache task in my Azure Devops build pipeline cause I want to cache my NPM packages so they don't have to be downloaded every time I run the build.

[image]

To cache the node_modules folder of my solution should I use **$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/node_modules** or just **node_modules** in the path input ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cache npm's `node_modules`, then the value of path should be `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm/lib/node_modules`.

You can click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm) for detailed information.